# City or post code search in same field

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search, postal-code

I have a search form containing both city and postcode fields. The search is queries a mysql database and returns relevant results.

To make things easier for the user is it possible to combine these two and allow either cities or postcodes to be entered into the field?

Thanks

Comment: u can do it like Marc B said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `is_numeric()` function (or regexp) to figure out which type of data you have in request (city name or postcode).

Answer (score 4):

It'd just mean an 'or' clause in your query, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE city='$formfield' OR postcode='$formfield'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A city name is probably not starting with numbers, so use that to filter, with a regular expression, and compare to the proper field.